# How to get rid of up and down arrow buttons from a lightning duallistbox?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds, lightning-duallistbox

The documentation doesn't seems to have that information covered. Did anyone had same issue figured a way to hide that column?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:dualListbox/specification) includes this attribute that you can use:

- **disableReordering**: Set to true to hide the Up and Down buttons used for reordering the Selected list items.